# How to store child classes in a database?

Tags: android, sql, database

I'm really new to databases, but I'm making a running tracker app in Android, and I have some classes that represent the type of goals that you can have on a single type of workout.

What every Goal class does actually is to store a value but together with a unit, like for example a DistanceGoal will represent its value in meters and provide methods to convert it to kilometers or miles. A PaceGoal value will represent minutes per kilometers, and so on.

Also, according to type of Goal I will then have to read all tracking stats to see if the user has achieved the objective or not.

So:

```java
interface Goal {

  long getGoalValue();

}

class TimeGoal implements Goal{}

class DistanceGoal implements Goal{}

class PaceGoal implements Goal{}

/* ...... */
```

Now this works well, although there may be a better way to solve this. The problem is that I need to store this in a database.
I have been using the Android room library, and I couldn't find any other way than to store each type of goal in its own table, so when I need to retrieve them I know what stored value represents what kind of goal.

But when I have to store a new goal, it will probably be given as its abstraction (the Goal interface), so I don't know in which table to store it.

The only solution I thought of is the Visitor Pattern, do any of you have a better solution for this?

I may have to make changes to the whole class hierarchy, but what really matters is to distinguish the unit from one value from the others, in order to read the tracking statistics accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the Goal classes serializable. Then you can serialize the Goal objects to a byte array that you can store in your database. When you retrieve the byte array from the database, you can deserialize it to get the Goal object back. When you Google `serializable java` you should get lots of information on how to do this.